# How to Upload a list of objects to Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing flutter app with FireStore.

I have declared a variable 'total' and List of  objects to be filled with some data from collection called 'cart', then upload these data to collection called 'orders'

This code grab the data from collection 'cart':

```
void submitOrder() async {

    List<CartItem> products =[];
    double total =0;
    CartItem temp= CartItem(customerId:'' ,itemId:'' ,id: '', title: '', quantity:0, price: 0);

    DatabaseService().cartCollection.getDocuments().then(

       (snapshot) => snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {

          temp = CartItem(
            customerId: user.uid, 
            itemId: doc.data['itemId'].toString(),
            id: doc.documentID.toString(), 
            title: doc.data['itemName'].toString(),
            quantity: int.tryParse(doc.data['quantity'].toString()) , 
            price: double.tryParse( doc.data['price'].toString()));

            total += temp.quantity*temp.price;
            print(total);  /// This print shows accurate total
            products.add(temp);
            }
          ),
        );
          // Send data to setOrderData in db class to set new doc in order collection                            
          DatabaseService().setOrderData(products, total, user.uid, branchId, 'open');

}
```

method setOrderData in DB class:

```
  // Add Order
Future setOrderData(List<CartItem> cartProducts, double total, String customerId, String branchId, String status ) async { 
    final timestamp = DateTime.now();
    return await orderCollection.document(uid).setData(
      {
        'customerId': customerId,
        'branchId': branchId,
        'status': status ,
        'amount': total.toString(), //
        'dateTime': timestamp.toIso8601String(),
        'products': cartProducts.map((cp) => {
          'id': cp.id,
          'title': cp.title,
          'quantity': cp.quantity,
          'price': cp.price,
          }).toList(),
      });
  }
```

data in FireStore shows that products and total are null?

Link to image:

[image: Data in Firestore]

If anyone can help me out I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **highly** recommend using a code formatter on your code, as it makes it much more likely that people can spot problems like the one you're having. When I reformat the first code block you shared, it becomes:

```
void submitOrder() async {
  List<CartItem> products = [];
  double total = 0;
  CartItem temp = CartItem(
      customerId: '', itemId: '', id: '', title: '', quantity: 0, price: 0);

  DatabaseService().cartCollection.getDocuments().then(
        (snapshot) => snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
          temp = CartItem(
              customerId: user.uid,
              itemId: doc.data['itemId'].toString(),
              id: doc.documentID.toString(),
              title: doc.data['itemName'].toString(),
              quantity: int.tryParse(doc.data['quantity'].toString()),
              price: double.tryParse(doc.data['price'].toString()));

          total += temp.quantity * temp.price;
          print(total);

          /// This print shows accurate total
          products.add(temp);
        }),
      );
  // Send data to setOrderData in db class to set new doc in order collection
  DatabaseService().setOrderData(products, total, user.uid, branchId, 'open');
}
```

An in this format it's immediately clear to me that you're calling `setOrderData` before any of the `products.add(temp)` calls have happened.

This is because data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously. Since this may take some time, your main code (including the `return`) continues so the UI is not blocked. Then when the data is available, your `then` callback is invoked.

This means that any code that needs the data from Firestore needs to be inside the `then` callback. So in your case, the solution could be as simple as moving the call to `setOrderData` to inside the `then`:

```
void submitOrder() async {
  List<CartItem> products = [];
  double total = 0;
  CartItem temp = CartItem(
      customerId: '', itemId: '', id: '', title: '', quantity: 0, price: 0);

  DatabaseService().cartCollection.getDocuments().then(
        (snapshot) => snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
          temp = CartItem(
              customerId: user.uid,
              itemId: doc.data['itemId'].toString(),
              id: doc.documentID.toString(),
              title: doc.data['itemName'].toString(),
              quantity: int.tryParse(doc.data['quantity'].toString()),
              price: double.tryParse(doc.data['price'].toString()));

          total += temp.quantity * temp.price;
          print(total);

          /// This print shows accurate total
          products.add(temp);
        }),
        // Send data to setOrderData in db class to set new doc in order collection
        DatabaseService().setOrderData(products, total, user.uid, branchId, 'open');
    );
}
```

So the things to take away from this:

1. Always format your code, as it makes it easier for you and others to understand the flow and find problems.
2. Data is loaded from Firestore (and most cloud APIs) asynchronously, and you can only use the data inside the `then()` callback, or by using `await`.

Comment: Thanks Frank, your comments means a lot to me!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope the explanation made sense, as you're likely to encounter this type of problem regularly when dealing with modern cloud (or even many local I/O) APIs. I know this sort of API takes time to get used to. I definitely recommend reading up on Dart's `async` / `await` keywords, as they tend to make this sort of code look more familiar. Just make sure to also learn how asynchronous APIs work without them, as it's the best way to work comfortably with them in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The best Practice to solve such an error is to use `try` and then `catch` with the `await` for each function like the below code

```
void submitOrder() async {
  List<CartItem> products = [];
  double total = 0;
  CartItem temp = CartItem(
      customerId: '', itemId: '', id: '', title: '', quantity: 0, price: 0);
  try {
    await DatabaseService().cartCollection.getDocuments().then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
            temp = CartItem(
                customerId: user.uid,
                itemId: doc.data['itemId'].toString(),
                id: doc.documentID.toString(),
                title: doc.data['itemName'].toString(),
                quantity: int.tryParse(doc.data['quantity'].toString()),
                price: double.tryParse(doc.data['price'].toString()));

            total += temp.quantity * temp.price;
            print(total);

            /// This print shows accurate total
            products.add(temp);
          }),
        );
    // Send data to setOrderData in db class to set new doc in order collection
    await DatabaseService()
        .setOrderData(products, total, user.uid, branchId, 'open');
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
```